# Create semi-circle blur effect on a Grid

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to develop a WindowsPhone 8 app with a home page like the fourth phone on this [page](http://inspirationmobile.tumblr.com/). The one with a mountain.

You can see an image with two layers over it. My problem is that I don't know how to call that effect in English, and also, I don't know how to do it.

Maybe I will need to make three copies of my image: one untouched, a second one with, a blur effect? and a third one with a 'bigger' blur effect.

Or maybe, I have to add two Grids with some white background and with an opacity less than 100%.

**How would you do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is just a good one, I would the samething, and I don't expect that application to be implementing something different, in détails I would do :

1. One Grid with High Blur on the background.
2. Another Grid with middle Blur on the front. I'll use an OpacityMask set to a RadialGradientBrush to create that ring effect just like in here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979637(v=vs.95).aspx
3. And one lase Grid with no Blur in the Front of The previous Grid again with a OpacityMask also set to a RadialGradientBrush.

The three Grids will all have the same Background TileBrush, example :

The Result I've made :

[image]

Code :

```
<StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="The effect you asked, with :" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="That's Clapton" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Eric_Clapton_Blur3.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" TranslateX="0.4" ScaleX="1.4"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <!-- This gradient stop is partially transparent. -->
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1" />
                    <!-- This gradient stop is partially transparent. -->
                    <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.741" />
                    <!-- This gradient stop is fully opaque. -->
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0.728" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Grid.OpacityMask>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Eric_Clapton_Blur2.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" TranslateX="0.4" ScaleY="0.6"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <!-- This gradient stop is partially transparent. -->
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1" />
                    <!-- This gradient stop is partially transparent. -->
                    <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.741" />
                    <!-- This gradient stop is fully opaque. -->
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0.728" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Grid.OpacityMask>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Eric_Clapton.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
```

I know I didn't do it with perfection, and I used terrible naming for the Elements, It's just I've just woke up, and didn't even take my breakfast, hope that helps.

Comment: Did you apply the blur effect on the image or on the grid? I've found three images on your code: Eric_Clapton.jpg, Eric_Clapton_Blur2.jpg and Eric_Clapton_Blur3.jpg.

Comment: Yeah there three images, one without blur, and for the two others I applied the blur externally using Gimp then I used them directly, note that the blur3 has more Blur than the blur2